How can I make sure I get a JSON OK 200 response? Using Laravel and WooCommerce Webhooks (Wordpress)
Im trying to do a simple Webhook connection. I have setup my Wordpress database using Xampp and activated a webhook for whenever an order is created in the 'shop'. It works fine since I managed to insert data into a DB by using a PHP file, but now, im trying to do the same with Laravel (requested for a project)
Im fairly new to it, and so far I've set the route in web.php as follows:
Route::post('webhook', [WebhookController::class, 'WebhookController']);

Then again, due to some recommendations I have added this line to the VerifyCsrfToken.php file:
protected $except = ['webhook'];

I have created a controller for the webhook as well, WebhookController.php:
class WebhookController extends Controller{
    public function handle(Request $request) {
        return response()->json('éxito');
    }
}

However, im not sure how it's supposed to work since I find little documentation on how to handle webhooks. Am I supposed to be seeing any sort of response in the Network tab of Developer Tools? Cause I see none.
In the project folder (and webhook config in wordpress), the webhook is pointing towards webhook/webhook.php. I have tried different configurations both changing the route in the Laravel config and where it points towards in Wordpress (I could make it point towards webhook/ in the Laravel route, but the WooCommerce plugin wont let me save changes if it isn't pointing towards a file).
Any clue as to what I could try? Sorry if its pretty obvious!
Further Testing
I have changed my route line because it was wrong to:
Route::post('webhook', [WebhookController::class, 'handle']);
since I must've mixed it while trying things.
I have changed where the woocommerce webhook points to to'localhost:8000/webhook' yet while having the active laravel server nothing comes through.
I have done a POST petition to localhost:8000/webhook using Postman, and I do in fact recieve 'éxito'. So I believe the problem must lay in between the webhook being sent and recieved by the Controller

I found what was causing the webhook not to point toward the path adequately.
All I had to do was paste this code under functions.php to bypass the unsafe URLs, and it worked. I believe that updating WooCommerce/WordPress resets the lines added, so it's better to do it with a plugin:
function allow_unsafe_urls($args) {
    $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;
    return $args;
}

add_filter('http_request_args', 'allow_unsafe_urls');

